# Adding two labels to an edge in TikZ, close to the endpoints

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm quite new to TikZ. I know how to make two nodes `A` and `B`, how to connect `A` and `B` by an edge with the `draw` command, and how to add a label to the edge. But now I want to add two labels: One close to the node `A`, and the other one close to the node `B`. What is the preferred way to do this? It would be nice to tell TikZ to place the label close to the endpoint (not colliding with the node), without giving the exact position.

Also, I would like edge-labels in a smaller font. Is there an easier way than adding some resizing command to each of the the labels?

This example illustrates what I want:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (2,4) {B};
\draw (A) to node[align=center] {first line should be smaller and close to B\\second line should be smaller and close to A} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a  minimal example document?

Comment: You can try `node [xshift=...,yshift=...] ...` . But I agree with Jake  you must provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: You can use the styles `at start`, `very near start`, `near start`, `midway`, `near end`, `very near end` and `at end` which translate to the `pos`itions 0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.875 and 1. You can also place `label`s at the start and end nodes, where you can define a `label distance`. — You can use the `font` key for font switching macros.

Comment: @Jake: I've added an example. Is this ok?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thanks! Now I know how to create two labels with `near start` and `near end`. Where exactly should I use the `font` keyword?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `near start` and `near end`.  I think this is what you're describing:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (2,4) {B};
\draw[font=\tiny] (A) to node[near end] {first line should be smaller and close to B} 
                         node[near start] {second line should be smaller and close to A} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To get even closer, you can use `very near start`.

Comment: Thanks. Just playing with the remarks in Qrrbrbirlbel's comment, I figured that I can add two `node`s to the same `\draw` command. However, I'm still not sure where to put the `font` keyword.

Comment: @azimut (and kmachinnis): Define a style, say `mini`, or use `every node`, that contains `font=\tiny`, and then you can say *(on one path):* `\draw[every node/.append style={font=\tiny}] (A) -- node[very near start] {…} node[very near end] {…} (B);`. Of course, you can also say `node [font=\tiny, very near start] …`.

Comment: Thanks-- is there an advantage to having mini as a style rather than `\tiny` in the node itself?

Comment: Why not : `\draw[font=\tiny] (A) to node[near end] {first line should be smaller and close to B}  node[near start] {second line should be smaller and close to A} (B);`?

Comment: @AlainMatthes Ah, I never know which node options can be assigned to paths and scopes and which need explicitly assigned to `every node` or a style.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel `font` is special like `line width`

Comment: Is there a way to generalise the use of this syntax? For example, could I label both ends of a line segment and put a label in the middle using one command? I've managed to do this, but I have to draw the line twice, which seems very inefficient.